# Pasar una cadena de caracteres como parámetro al instanciar una clase

Tags: string, clase, objeto, constructor, parametros

Soy un aprendiz en C++, actualmente entrando en la programación orientada a objetos. El día de hoy empecé con este tema, y me ha surgido el siguiente problema:

Cuando intento pasar por parámetro una cadena de caracteres (tipo char) a un constructor a la hora de instanciar una clase, o bien a un método de una clase (objeto.metodo), no puedo pasar la cadena de caracteres por parametros, sino que solo puedo pasar otros tipo de datos (int, float, bool, etc).

```
#include <iostream>

class Ejemplo {
    int num;
    char nombre[10];
public:
    Ejemplo(int, char*);
};

Ejemplo::Ejemplo(int _num, char* _nombre) {
    num = _num;
    for (int i = 0; _nombre[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        nombre[i] = _nombre[i];
}
}

int main() {
    Ejemplo hola(10, "ejemplo"); // Aqui el error, dejo captura
}
```

Este es el mensaje que da Visual Studio:

1>E:\C Proyects\Clases3\Clases3.cpp(22,29): error C2664: 'Ejemplo::Ejemplo(Ejemplo &&)': el argumento 2 no puede convertirse de 'const char [8]' a 'char *'

1>E:\C Proyects\Clases3\Clases3.cpp(22,19): message : Conversión de literal de cadena pierde calificador const (ver /Zc:strictStrings)

1>E:\C Proyects\Clases3\Clases3.cpp(12,10): message : vea la declaración de 'Ejemplo::Ejemplo'
1>Compilación del proyecto "Clases3.vcxproj" terminada -- ERROR.

Será posible el paso de parámetros usando el tipo char en una clase?. Entiendo que en c++ se suele usar la clase string para manejar cadena de caracteres, de hecho quizás con la clase string no tenga problemas, sin embargo no quisiera dejar esto en el aire y quedarme con la incertidumbre. Prefiero entender como funciona y por que no puedo hacer el paso de parámetros de esa forma.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar un casting sobre la cadena que pasas por parámetro.

```
int main() {
    Ejemplo hola(10, (char*)"ejemplo"); // Aqui el error, dejo captura
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En C++ los literales de cadenas son inalterables. Para que eso se cumpla tienen como
tipo "arreglo de char constante" (`const char[]`). Ese tipo no puede ser convertido
implicitamente a un "puntero a char" (`char *`) porque permitiria escribir a los
caracteres individuales, aún cuando la cadena es inmutable.

Para solucionar ese problema, y poder copiar la cadena tendrias que declarar `_nombre`
como un "puntero a un char constante" (`const char*`) en el constructor.

Sin embargo, aún esta el problema de que solo puedes pasarle cadenas con longitud menor
a 10 a tu constructor (porque declaraste a `nombre` como un arreglo de diez caracteres).
Para eso sería más facil declarar a `nombre` y `_nombre` como `std::string`, y con eso
nos ahorramos escribir el código para copiar la cadena. Por ejemplo:

```
class Ejemplo {
    int num;
    std::string nombre;
public:
    Ejemplo(int, std::string);
};

Ejemplo::Ejemplo(int _num, std::string _nombre) {
    num = _num;
    nombre = _nombre;
}

int main() {
    Ejemplo hola(10, "ejemplo"); // Aqui el error, dejo captura
}
```